# Is the past participle in passé composé variable to number/gender if *en* is put before it?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, participe-passé, passé-composé

I have found the following sentence:

> J’**en** ai **reçus**, des courriers de sa part !

I thought the conjugated past participle is *reçu* since the auxiliary is *avoir*, and also the content of *en* is put after the past participle. However, I found the correct form was *reçus*.

Now, what made me confused is [the following article](https://www.scribens.fr/Exp/AccordVerbe/Participe_passe.html) (the bold decoration is by me):

> 3. Participe passé conjugué avec le verbe avoir
>
> Le participe passé conjugué avec le verbe avoir reste invariable sauf si le COD est placé avant le verbe.
>
> Exception 1 : Si le COD est le pronom en, le participe passé demeure invariable.
>
> Ex : Des kilomètres, j'**en** ai **parcouru** des centaines.

So which is the correct one here?

Comment: @LPH English is not my native language...

Comment: @LPH I already did it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual rule is that there is no agreement when the pronoun ***en*** is used and is the direct object of the verb.

However, it can be argued that *en* might be considered an indirect object of *recevoir* that replaces *de sa part*. In that case the agreement is possible but would require *des courriers* to be located before the past participle, which isn't the case.

The following would work though:

> *Des courriers de sa part, j'en ai reçu**s** !*

There is a second kind of exception described here, from the [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) :

> **Rem.** Accord de la forme adj. du verbe. Lorsque en est compl. d'obj. d'un part. passé conjugué avec avoir et qu'il le précède, le part. passé est gén. invar. On justifie l'invariabilité en disant que ,,en est un neutre partitif signifiant « de cela, une partie de cela » et qu'il est (...) complément déterminatif du nom partie (ou quantité) sous entendu`` (Grev. 1969, § 795). L'usage toutefois est indécis et en relation avec un adv. de quantité (beaucoup, combien, tant), le part. passé peut s'accorder. *Combien j'en [d'hommes] ai déjà passés ! combien j'en puis encore atteindre ! pourquoi mon égal irait-il plus loin que moi ?* (Guéhenno, Jean-Jacques, 1952, p. 32). Mais, là encore, la règle est imprécise et précaire. *J'en ai tant vu des rois !* (Hugo, *Feuilles automne*, III, ds Grev. 1969, § 795). Il faut noter enfin que l'arrêté du J.O. du 9 févr. 1977 admet l'un et l'autre accord.

Another interpretation would be that in the first sentence, the quantity adverb *comme* is implied so the sentence is really:

> *Comme j'en ai reçu**s**, des courriers de sa part !*

In that case, the agreement is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Voici une liste de références à consulter sur l'accord avec *en* :

1/ https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-27694.php

> Lorsque "en"  a le sens de : de cela, une partie de cela, le participe
>   passé est, généralement, invariable.
>
> Des livres, j'en ai lu beaucoup.
>
> Avec les adverbes de quantité, si  "en" est un COD, le participe passé
>   sera  invariable également :
>
> Des livres, je ne sais combien j'en ai lu !
>
> Quand, en plus de "en", la phrase contient un COD comme dans cette
>   phrase :
>
> Ce livre est une mine d'or, je ne te dis pas les enseignements que
>   j'en ai tirés
>
> "en"  n'est pas COD, donc la règle de l'accord invariable ne
>   s'applique pas, le COD étant "que", mis à la place de "les
>   enseignements".
>
> Conclusion
>
> **Le participe ne s'accorde pas, quand le pronom "en" est employé sans le pronom relatif "que". Le participe s'accorde, quand le pronom "en"
>   est employé avec le pronom relatif "que".**

2/ https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-du-participe-passe-precede-de-en-184.php

> » A. Si en est C.O.D. Si en est C.O.D., on considère alors qu'il n'a
>   ni genre, ni nombre. Le participe passé qui le suit ne s'accorde pas.
>   Exemples : Des bonbons ? Il en a mangé beaucoup ! / De ces bonbons,
>   combien en avez-vous mangé? / De ces bonbons, j'en ai beaucoup mangé.
>
> » B. Si en est C.O.I. Si en est C.O.I., il peut alors être supprimé
>   sans affecter le sens de la phrase. Le participe passé s'accorde alors
>   avec son C.O.D.. Exemple : Ce manteau a eu un grand succès commercial
>   : les copies qu'on en a faites sont nombreuses.

3/ http://www.aidenet.eu/conjugaison44.htm (plus exhaustif)

4/ http://www.visezjuste.uottawa.ca/pages/grammaire/pp_avec_avoir_cas_particuliers_3.html (ibid.)